# Using procdump as AeDebug tool, how can I change dump directory?

Tags: procdump

I'm using procdump to create minidump automatically when process is crashed. It works with the following syntax:

```
procdump64 -i
```

But the dump folder is `C:\Users\Administrator`, how can I change to `C:\dumps`?

I tried to use `procdump64 -j c:\dumps -i` and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

(That's some time since this question was posted, but it worth an answer)

(For convenience, I'll use `procdump` (instead of `procdump64`)

From the question, it's implied that executing the following should just work (in the OP's use case, writing a dump to `C:\Users\Administrator`):

```
procdump -i
```

...but at least on my end, it doesn't.

It seems mandatory to specifiy *what type* of dump should be written ("Full" (`-ma`), "Mini" (`-mm`), etc). The dump types can be listed by simply executing `procdump`.

Back to the question, the following should work,:

```
procdump -ma -i c:\dumps
```

Note that if the destination folder requires administrator permissions, this might not work, even if `procdump` is ran under a run-as-administrator cmd (that's what I [experienced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67221163/using-procdump-to-listen-to-all-exceptions-doesnt-work/67268547#67268547)).