# Using procdump to listen to all exceptions doesn't work

Tags: .net, debugging, exception, procdump

I want `procdump` to listen to all exceptions (without having to specify a process name or id).

From [an example given here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump#examples), I thought using the following should work:

```
procdump -ma -i
```

...but although I get the message following message:

```
ProcDump is now set as the Just-in-time (AeDebug) debugger.
```

...when an exception occurs in some process, nothing gets dumped.

The exception is intentionally thrown from the following .NET code:

```
using System;

namespace ProcdumpTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (ShouldAwaitKeyPress(args)) Console.ReadLine();
            Throw();
        }
        static void Throw()
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        static bool ShouldAwaitKeyPress(string[] args)
        {
            var shouldAwaitKeyPress = false;
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
               bool.TryParse(args[0], out shouldAwaitKeyPress);
            }
            return shouldAwaitKeyPress;
        }
    }
}
```

Compile it and run with either `ProcdumpTest` or `ProcdumpTest false` so that an exception is thrown immediately, or with `ProcdumpTest true` so that it waits for a keypress to throw.

Comment: @HansPassant, by that link you mean I should set the appropriate registry settings? executing `procdump -ma -i` already does that.

Comment: @OfirD Everything seems correct so there could be another setting in your system that's interferring here. Have you tried running procmon? Does it show WerFault.exe starting as a child process of your app? WerFault.exe should then start procdump.

Comment: @Sebastian, thank you! I wasn't familiar with working with procmon, so following your comment I played with it and finally the problem was visible: I installed procdump under `C:\Program Files`, which requires admin permissions. Although I registered procdump under cmd as admin, procmon indicated that the dump file write access was denied. I then changed the destination dump folder to a non-admin folder, and the dump was then created. Want to post that as an answer to get the bounty?

Comment: @OfirD It's not necessary :) I am happy I helped and, in fact, you figured the problem on your own. I thought it could be caused by some registry setting or a file system problem. Sometimes you need to analyze all the accessed registry keys to find which one is problematic. Fortunately here, it was easier :) Procmon is almost always the first tool I run when diagnosing problems on Windows :)

Comment: @Sebastian, I appreciate your help, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved thanks to @Sebastian's help:

I initially installed `procdump` under `C:\Program Files`, which requires admin permissions, and although I executed `procdump -i -ma` under a run-as-administrator cmd, procmon indicated that the dump file write-access was denied.

After changing the destination dump folder to a non-admin folder, the dump was successfuly created:

```
procdump -ma -i c:\path\to\some\non\admin\folder
```